# ASP.NET Razor Pages app login with Google and Firebase

Tags: firebase-authentication, google-oauth

I'm trying to create an ASP.NET razor pages app to login with Google and firebase authentication and access some firebase information.  I have used the login with google script to get an ID token.  I've passed that back to my razor page, and and using the FirebaseAuthentication.net package, I try to sign in with credential.

```
<script>
    function handleCredentialResponse(response) {
        console.log("Encoded JWT ID token: " + response.credential);
        fetch('/login?handler=google_signin&token=' + response.credential, {
            method:'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({"token": response.credential}),
            headers:
            {
                "RequestVerificationToken": '@GetAntiXsrfRequestToken()'
            },
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(response => console.log(JSON.stringify(response)))
    }
    window.onload = function () {
        google.accounts.id.initialize({
            client_id: "myid.apps.googleusercontent.com",
            callback: handleCredentialResponse
        });
        google.accounts.id.renderButton(
            document.getElementById("buttonDiv"),
            { theme: "outline", size: "large" }  // customization attributes
        );
    }
</script>



public async Task<JsonResult> OnPostGoogle_Signin(string token)
        {                
            try
            {
                var x = await _firebaseAuth.SignInWithCredentialAsync(GoogleProvider.GetCredential(token));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw;
            }               

            Console.WriteLine(token);
            return new JsonResult("{'token':" + token + "}");
        }
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuthHttpException: Exception occured during Firebase Http request.
Url: https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyAssertion?key=xxxxx
Request Data: {"requestUri":"https://myapp.firebaseapp.com","postBody":"access_token=myaccesstoken&providerId=google.com","returnIdpCredential":true,"returnSecureToken":true}
Response: {
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "INVALID_IDP_RESPONSE : Unsuccessful check authorization response from Google: {\n  \"error_description\": \"Invalid Value\"\n}\n",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "INVALID_IDP_RESPONSE : Unsuccessful check authorization response from Google: {\n  \"error_description\": \"Invalid Value\"\n}\n",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalid"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm sure there's something I'm not understanding with the token, or something there.  Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?